# Can someone help me to explain what is wrong in my c code?

Tags: c

So first of all, here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

double total(double assignment, double mid, double final){
    double totalScore;

    totalScore = (assignment * 0.2) + (mid * 0.3) + (final * 0.5);

    return totalScore;
}

char grade(char Z, char X, char Y, char P){



    char gradeAchieved;

    if (total(assignment, mid, final) >= 80 )`{
        gradeAchieved = Z;
    }
    else if ((total(assignment, mid, final) >= 70) && (total(assignment, mid, final) < 80)  ){
        gradeAchieved = X;
    }
    else if ((total(assignment, mid, final) >= 60) && (total(assignment, mid, final) < 70)  ){
        gradeAchieved = Y;
    }
    else if (total(assignment, mid, final) < 60){
        gradeAchieved = P;
    }
    return gradeAchieved;
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    char A = 'A';
    char B = 'B';
    char C = 'C';
    char D = 'D';
    printf("Input your assignment score: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("Input your midtest score: ");
    scanf("%lf", &y);
    printf("Input your final test score: ");
    scanf("%lf", &z);

    printf("Your total score is: %lf", total(x, y, z));
    printf("Your grade is: %c", grade(A, B, C, D));


    return 0;
}
```

in my code, its supposed that when I run it, you will get a prompt to input your assignment, mid, and final grade. Then it will calculate your final score and decides whether you get an A, B, C, or D. But it seems that every time i tried to run it, i got this error message:

```
main.c: In function ‘grade’:
main.c:17:15: error: ‘assignment’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (total(assignment, mid, final) >= 80 ){
               ^~~~~~~~~~
main.c:17:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:17:27: error: ‘mid’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (total(assignment, mid, final) >= 80 ){
                           ^~~
main.c:17:32: error: ‘final’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (total(assignment, mid, final) >= 80 ){
                                ^~~~~
```

And I don't really know how to solve it. So could anybody help me? And sorry for my bad english

Comment: How can grade know what assignment is?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil I am pointing the OP or anyone else that wants to take the time to write an answer in the direction I don't see how rethorical is that the variable is not declared in the scope. I may be mistaken but I would like to learn if I am, please post a version that works without taking as arguments the missing variables.

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez: My point is you are **not** pointing that out to the OP. Getting to that conclusion requires knowledge about the rules of C that there is no reason to believe the OP has. As I wrote, the conclusion cannot be derived by logic alone. It is necessary to actually explain the rules, and that is why merely asking the question you propose is not a good technique for teaching in this situation.

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez:  To you, it may be obvious that `grade` does not know what `assignment` is because `assignment` is not in scope. But you know the scope rules. Asking the question could be a way of pointing out the lack of visibility of `assignment` to somebody who knows the scope rules. But to somebody who does not know the scope rules, the question is meaningless. Students have to be taught those rules, and, when teaching, it is important to think about what things the student does not or may not yet know. It is important not to take things you know as automatically known to others.

Comment: You are right, in fact this is actually a common error that when learning to use functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the three error messages is that you haven't declared any variables named `assignment`, `mid`, and/or `final` in your function `grade()`. You could move the four `char` variables into the `grade()` function and change the function parameters to match `total()` and your code should run.

```
char grade(double assignment, double mid, double final){

    char A = 'A';
    char B = 'B';
    char C = 'C';
    char D = 'D';

    char gradeAchieved;

    if (total(assignment, mid, final) >= 80 ) {
        gradeAchieved = A;
    }
    else if ((total(assignment, mid, final) >= 70) && (total(assignment, mid, final) < 80)  ){
        gradeAchieved = B;
    }
    else if ((total(assignment, mid, final) >= 60) && (total(assignment, mid, final) < 70)  ){
        gradeAchieved = C;
    }
    else if (total(assignment, mid, final) < 60){
        gradeAchieved = D;
    }
    return gradeAchieved;
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    printf("Input your assignment score: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("Input your midtest score: ");
    scanf("%lf", &y);
    printf("Input your final test score: ");
    scanf("%lf", &z);

    printf("Your total score is: %lf", total(x, y, z));
    printf("Your grade is: %c", grade(x, y, z));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code can be a lot simpler by omitting the `(total(assignment, mid, final) < 80` checks and all intermediate variables and just using `return 'A';` in each branch (or whatever grade corresponds to that branch). Last branch be omitted entirely in favor of `return 'D';`. You can store `total(...)` in a variable instead of recomputing it multiple times though (and `total` itself could just `return` the computation instead of using a temp var, although that's omitted).